# PHP Image Display using my code

Tags: php, image, displaytag

First File

```
<body>

    <form action="_31_upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<body>
```

Second File

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} 
else 

{
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$img = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
echo $img;


}


?> 
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" height="200" width="200">
```

**My program is working well. But help me regarding IMAGE display using this code.**

I am using img tag, and src attribute as well. but image is not displayed on webpage.

Comment: Where do you want to display the image. For html,
Use <img> tag to display your image with "src" as your path of image.

Comment: at your PHP code move the uploaded file from TEMP location to public path (inside your apache public_html folder) and then input in a <img src="PUBLIC PATH TO YOUR IMAGE"> .. and a good suggestion from me is to use some ready library to handle image uploads .. this is much more secure and easy for beginners :) > https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ like that library

Comment: <img src="path/filename.jpg">

Comment: Yes Dear! I am also trying <img> tag, but not success, please give me code regarding

Comment: The uploaded file is an Image..???

Comment: Please update the code in your question.

Comment: Respected TBI,

I am update question.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } 
    else 

    {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];


      $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "./$name");

      echo '<img src="'.$name.'" />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: My File is successfully Work.

Thank you once again!

Comment: @TBI I cannot answer this question now because this question has this accepted answer..??